# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Downloads/BetterLifeIndex2015.csv' does not exist: b'Downloads/BetterLifeIndex2015.csv'

Tags: csv

**Resolved**

Answer: Changed the path, it was in fact inncorect path after all. Used absolute path (alt+d+copy from file explorer". Also used "r" before the path so the path is treated like a raw string.

```
# load the data
BetterLifeIndex = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\brede\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Downloads\BetterLifeIndex2015.csv", thousands = ',')
gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\brede\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Downloads\gdpcapita.csv", thousands= ',', delimiter ='\t',
encoding = 'latin1' , na_values="n/a")
```

Im new to Python and I'm running a Example from a machine learning book. I cant get python to read my csv file.

Code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.linear_model


def prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita):
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli[oecd_bli["INEQUALITY"]=="TOT"]
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli.pivot(index="Country", columns="Indicator", values="Value")
    gdp_per_capita.rename(columns={"2015": "GDP per capita"}, inplace=True)
    gdp_per_capita.set_index("Country", inplace=True)
    full_country_stats = pd.merge(left=oecd_bli, right=gdp_per_capita,
                                  left_index=True, right_index=True)
    full_country_stats.sort_values(by="GDP per capita", inplace=True)
    remove_indices = [0, 1, 6, 8, 33, 34, 35]
    keep_indices = list(set(range(36)) - set(remove_indices))
    return full_country_stats[["GDP per capita", 'Life satisfaction']].iloc[keep_indices]

# load the data
oecd_bli = pd.read_csv("Downloads/BetterLifeIndex2015.csv", thousands = ',')
gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/brede/Downloads/gdpcapita.csv", thousands= ',', delimiter ='\t',
encoding = 'latin1' , na_values="n/a")

#prepare the data
country_stats = prepare_country_stats (oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita)
x = np.c_[country_stats["gdp per capita"]]
y = np.c_[country_stats["life satisfaction"]]

#visualize the data 
country_stats.plot(kind= 'scatter' , x = "GDP per capita", y ='Life satisfaction')

#select a linear model
model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()

#train the model
model.fit (x, y)

#make a prediction for Cyprus
X_new = [[22587]] #Cyprus GDP per capita
print(model.predict(X_new)) #outputs[[5.96242338]]
```

The output is:

```
runfile('C:/Users/brede/Downloads/practice_gdp.py', wdir='C:/Users/brede/Downloads')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-59-2f130edd277c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/brede/Downloads/practice_gdp.py', wdir='C:/Users/brede/Downloads')

  File "C:\Users\brede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\brede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/brede/Downloads/practice_gdp.py", line 31, in <module>
    oecd_bli = pd.read_csv("Downloads/BetterLifeIndex2015.csv", thousands = ',')

  File "C:\Users\brede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\brede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\brede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\Users\brede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1135, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

  File "C:\Users\brede\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1917, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 689, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Downloads/BetterLifeIndex2015.csv' does not exist: b'Downloads/BetterLifeIndex2015.csv'
```

I have triplechecked the path to the file, and I can't seem to figure this out! All help is appreciated.

This is done in Spyder, also tried in Jupyter with same result. I've even copied the path etc.

help...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to include'/' in the file path.Try that 'C:/Users/brede/OneDrive....'